# C++: Implement different methods when called on OBJ, OBJ&, const OBJ&

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

Is there a way (I suspect it involves inheritance and polymorphism) to differentiate between `OBJ o, OBJ& o, const OBJ& o`? I wish to use the same code in 3 different programs, and have the same method name call different methods.

```
int main(){    
    try{
        // try something
    }catch(OBJ o){
        o.doSomething();    // Do action 1
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    try{
        // try something
    }catch(OBJ& o){
        o.doSomething();    // Do action 2
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    try{
        // try something
    }catch(const OBJ& o){
        o.doSomething();    // Do action 3
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Whatever the exception type, either the first `catch` clause will catch it, or none of the three will. Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Nope, do you have some context for why you'd want that?

Comment: You both are right, I'll clarify the question in a few minutes.

Comment: Clarified, could you take a look again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, through polymorphism you can make a function with the same header (declaration) take different forms (that's the meaning of the word - *polys, "many, much" and morphe, "form, shape"*), in our case, executing different instructions. Of course, the function must be a method for two classes, of which one inherits the other. Each class shall implement the function as it needs. Also, you will make a reference to a base class actually refer to an object of a derived class (poly morphe - *same thing, many forms*), thus obtaining the desired behavior.

Consider the following code:

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    virtual void call() const { cout<<"I am const function 'call' from BaseClass\n"; };
    virtual void call() { cout<<"I am function 'call' from BaseClass\n"; }
};

class DerivedClass1: public BaseClass{
public:
    void call() {  cout<<"I am function 'call' from DerivedClass1\n"; }
};

class DerivedClass2: public BaseClass{
public:
    void call() const {  cout<<"I am const function 'call' from DerivedClass2\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass b;
    DerivedClass1 d1;
    DerivedClass2 d2;

    try{
        throw b;
    }
    catch (BaseClass ex){
        ex.call();
    }

    try{
        throw d1;
    }
    catch (BaseClass& ex){
        ex.call();
    }

    try{
        throw d2;
    }
    catch (const BaseClass& ex){
        ex.call();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
I am function 'call' from BaseClass
I am function 'call' from DerivedClass1
I am const function 'call' from DerivedClass2
```

Notice that there are 2 virtual functions in the BaseClass, since

```
void call() const
```

is different from

```
void call()
```

You can read more about polymorphism here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-functions-and-runtime-polymorphism-in-c-set-1-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

You can have members called on a distinction between lvalue reference and rvalue reference but if you have a "void member() const &" you cannot have a plain "void member() const", you could however have "void member() const &&".